# there is a way to fix "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key"?

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, expo, react-native-flatlist

Is there a way to fix this warning?

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key

I got this warning every time and don't understand how to fix it.
I try to fix it but i realize that something wrong in my way .
hope to understand whats wrong because its so annoying.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, Platform, FlatList, Dimensions, Image } from 'react-native';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons'
import HeaderButton from '../components/HeaderButton';
import axios from 'axios';


const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class PlacesListScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isLoading: true, data: [] };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    data: res.data,
                })
                console.log(res.data);
            })
    }

    renderItem(item) {
        const { title, artist } = item.item;
        return (
            <View style={styles.itemView}>
                <View style={styles.imgContainer}>
                    {/* <Image style={styles.imageStyle}
                        source={{ uri: image }}
                    /> */}
                </View>

                <View style={styles.itemInfo}>
                    <Text style={styles.name}>
                        {title+ ' ' + artist}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.vertical} numberOfLines={1}>{title} |</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
                    <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20 }}>loading...</Text>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                </View>
            )
        }


        return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.data}
                        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                    />
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

Hope that you understand my problem and how can I fix it.
the example code above shows my try to get some data from API, but it returns a warning every time about 
each child in a list should have a unique "key".

Comment: This may be helpful: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#renderitem

Comment: Try refactoring keyExtractor to this: (item, index) => item.id.toString().
I know it seems dumb but it works for me

Comment: what is the "index" in my case ? where should i put him on my case ?

Comment: it doesnt work ..and i dont know why

Comment: the warning is from the `FlatList` . just add `listKey ="' //whatever name you want ` to your `FlatList`

Comment: i add listKey ='frog'  and get the same error..

Answer (score 0):

console.log the key of each item. It may be possible u have the same id for some items?

Comment: It's not a good practice at all to have different items with same id. The best way is to make your data to have unique id for each item. If it's not doable, you can try:
 `keyExtractor={item => item.id + Math.random()}`
it's not a good practice for large scale project, but it can fix the problem

Comment: It does not work because even if you extract the `id` with `item.id` if the item.id is not unique for each element it'll give this error. Either make all of the ids unique or give it a unique identifier to use as key.

Could you show a sample of your item object?

Also, it should work because Howard is using a Math.random() in it.